# C# form application moving from page to page

Tags: c#

I am building a game. I have a Menu page, with a "Start" button. I would like to know how I can make the button direct the user to a new page with the game. I thought of simply changing all buttons' and labels' visibility to false, but that would be very messy. I thought of closing the form and reopening a new one as said here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/936c8ca3-0809-4ddb-890c-426521fe60f1/c-open-a-new-form-and-close-a-form?forum=winforms

Like this:

```
public static void ThreadProc()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form());
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        t.Start();
        this.Close();
    }
```

but when I click the button, you can see the form closing and reopening again, and it doesn't even reopen at the same coordinates.
Is there any way to do such a thing? I want it to move from page to page as it would if this was a website. Is this possible? If so how? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Create more forms. When use click the button open the next form instead of closing and reopening current one. Do you need help with that?

Comment: Use Panels instead of different forms. Hide the current panel, and show the next panel.

Comment: Make a plan of all the forms you will need. Also on their relation: will they cooperate? will the be open together or not and where will they be, which sizes etc..? Then you can decide if you want several forms or one with a tab and tabpages or on with panels or usercontrols or a mix..

Answer (score 0):

Use `UserControl`s for every view you need and then switch between them in your code by adding/removing them to/from your form.

Example: The start-page is a `UserControl` containing the button that starts the game. The game UI is another `UserControl` that contains all the logic and visuals for your game.

You could then use something like he following:

```
public class StartView : UserControl
{
    ...

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise a separate event upon the button being clicked
        if (StartButtonPressed != null)
            StartButtonPressed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> StartButtonPressed;
}

public class GameView : UserControl
{
    ...
}

public UserControl SwitchView(UserControl newView)
{
    UserControl oldControl = null;
    if (this.Controls.Count > 0)
    {   oldControl = (UserControl)this.Controls[0];
        this.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    this.Controls.Add(newView);
    newView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    return oldControl;
}
```

You can now create the start view in `Form_Load`:

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartView v = new StartView();
    v.StartButtonPressed += StartButtonPressed;
    SwitchView(v);
}
```

The event handler that reacts to the start button being pressed would do this:

```
public void StartButtonPressed(object senderView, EventArgs e)
{
    GameView v = new GameView();
    UserControl old = SwitchView(v);
    if (old != null)
        old.Dispose();
}
```